# How to pass Splunk Token Value into Slack block( json Code )when alert trigger in Splunk

Tags: python-3.x, webhooks, slack, slack-api, splunk

Any one how to Configure Webhook in Splunk by using the default option which is available in Splunk and how to add payload as there is no other options are available as shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQ5pv.png)

I am using Splunk App and able to get trigger alert notification inside my Slack Channel but i wanted to modify text format.

```
Your Testing Alert alert matched 5 Events At 1600318446.014216
Please Click on below link to View Alert: http://Shailesh-Yadav:8000/app/search/alert?s=%2FservicesNS%2Fnobody%2Fsearch%2Fsaved%2Fsearches%2FTesting%2BAlert
Type of Alert : alert
Owner of Alert is : shaileshyadav
Trigger Date: 2020-09-17
Job Level: Testing Alert
Job Run Duration: 0.169
Job Search ID: scheduler__shaileshyadav__search__RMD511208c77f51c333d_at_1600318440_23
Priority:1
```

I have Checked and found that there is an option for message formatting.we Can use json payload and by using Curl command we Can send it to Webhook URL.
for example

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @/Users/shaileshyadaav/Desktop/splunk.json https://hooks.slack.com/services/YFVGJDSF3784865/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYY
```

Problem facing:how i Can pass the Splunk token value inside my json file on real time basis when event trigger(which is i am able to get by using Splunk APP but format is not as expected).

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a custom payload using Webhook alert action. By default it will send a payload which contains:

- Search ID or SID for the saved search that triggered the alert
- Link to search results
- Search owner and app
- First result row from the triggering search results

ref: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.2/Alert/Webhooks

So the only degree of freedom is in changing or customizing values returned in the first result row. Should you need more advanced custom alert action, have a look at https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/2878/

See this example where the column name is changed to a custom value and passed via webhook when alert condition is triggered.

[image]
[image]